# Self-closing tags (void elements) in HTML5

Tags: html, tags, element

Step 6 of *8.1.2.1 Start tags* of the HTML5 spec says that [void elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#void-elements) may have a single `/` character. I think this is so it's easier to migrate sites that are XHTML over to HTML5.

What's the best practice?

E.g., if I'm making a website with HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`), which should I do?

1. without the slash

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   ```
2. with the slash

   ```
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   ```

If both render correctly on all browsers, then I'm assuming (1) without the slash is the way to go since it's more HTML5.

Comment: Just as a reminder... in HTML5 you can replace that big meta declaration for this: `<meta charset=utf-8>` (it's a shorthand just for this purpose and it's a valid equivalent).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no consensus on best practice, and according to the author of the spec, Ian Hickson, it does not matter.

Comment: Do you have a link to something indicating this stance by Ian Hickson?

Comment: http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2006-December/008235.html and http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2006-December/008312.html and see also other answers in this thread.

Comment: They are both valid (for HTML, not XHTML), and adding the / is just adding more characters to download.

Comment: Good point, but usually there's a difference between official spec definiton and browser implementation. Does somebody have a good ressource that shows browser compat ?

Comment: Panique - all browsers do "support" the /> in HTML - even though it was invalid HTML prior to version 4 - in order to be backwards compatible with the earliest versions of Netscape and because /> is used all over the web. You won't find a compatibility table because it doesn't need one, no widely used browser has an issue with this.

Answer (score 19):

Closing the tag with a slash is a more explicit way of denoting that it is not meant to have a closing tag.

Answer (score 16):

Mostly it depends if you want to go the XML route or not. Both should render correctly, as the HTML5 spec does not require self-closing tags - their only reason is that the document is then valid XML.

The easier way is to probably just write then without the self-closing "/", unless there's a specific need to get the markup parsed as XML - in that case you also need

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" >
```

Comment: Just to clarify. By "in that case," you mean for XML.

Comment: Yes. XML requires a namespace and that gives the HTML document an XML namespace.

Answer (score 14):

Google suggests in its [style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Document_Type#Document_Type): **do not close void elements**.

> HTML5 (HTML syntax) is preferred for all HTML documents ... Although fine with HTML, do not close void elements

Personally I've gotten used to closing tags with a slash, and find that `/>` helps me to recognize that the tag will not have a closing tag.

Comment: Regarding your final sentence - it will not have a closing tag because it is a void element.  The slash is confusing to html newbies like me because its presence suggests that the slash closes the element.

Comment: I think that the closing tag can be helpful for identifying void elements (see @nbsp's answer). It may be confusing at first for newbies, but it is an important syntax to know because you'll likely end up seeing it some day if/when you have to work with XML or XHTML.

Answer (score 6):

This article explains the difference between the two versions: http://www.colorglare.com/2014/02/03/to-close-or-not-to-close.html

The two versions are completely identical.

> Actually, one might argue that adding "/` to a void tag is an ignored syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your HTML 5 document compatible with XHTML and HTML (provided that you use the same subset of elements) and you potentially want to make it parsable with an XML parser I would suggest to close the void elements (self closing).

Looking at the guides, references and samples in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML they are self closing the void elements (but there exist as well guides, references and samples that are not self closing the void elements).