# Do we still need forward slashes when closing void elements in HTML5?

Tags: html, xhtml

In HTML5, do we still need the end slash like in XHTML?

```
<img src="some_image.png" />
```

validator.w3.org didn't complain if I dropped it, not even a warning. But some online documents seem to indicate the end slash is still required for tags such as img, link, meta, br, etc.

Comment: *Still*? Did any version of HTML require closing all tags?

Comment: @Gabe XHTML 1.0 Strict needs it. I mean, web pages will load fine usually, but it's considered invalid.

Comment: Yes, but that X isn't just there because X is cool, there's quite a gap between HTML and XHTML.

Comment: @Capt: You are correct, but that should *only* be an issue if your doctype indicates XHTML.

Comment: All the answers specify that you *can* either have the slash or no, but none of answers really explain why there are two alternative versions for defining void elements. I have also encountered term "self-closing" tag, which makes it even more confusing - are self-closing elements void elements? or they are similar to void, but with ending slash? anyways - this is quite inconsistent in HTML.

Comment: Interesting possible bug use case  in `Note` section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element#self-closing_tags
"If a trailing / (slash) character in a start tag is directly preceded by an unquoted attribute value — with no space between — the slash becomes a part of the attribute value rather than being discarded by the parser. For example, the markup `<img src=http://www.example.com/logo.svg/>` results in the src attribute having the value `http://www.example.com/logo.svg/` — which makes the URL wrong."

Answer (score 87, accepted):

`img` tags are Void Elements so they do not need an end tag.

> Void elements
>   area, base, br, col, command, embed, hr, img, input, keygen, link, meta, param, source, track, wbr

...

> Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

[W3C](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/syntax.html) | [WHATWG](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements)

That being said it's not strict parsing in HTML5 so it won't do any major harm.

Comment: Just curious, because my editor (Komodo) indents if I type '<img src="x">' and hit enter. It expects the trailing slash in HTML5 mode and I wanted to make sure this was correct behavior.

Comment: This is HTML, not XHTML, so it's not required. Fortunately, parsers still understand the XHTML-style end-slashes just fine, so there's no harm in leaving it there. Means easier converting backwards to XHTML, if necessary for whatever reason.

Comment: that's really weird. Why `schema.org` has end tags on imgs? Look here: `http://schema.org/Person`

Comment: @FreeRadical: A trailing slash is optional for a void element, but an end *tag* would be invalid.

Comment: While the question is about *end slashes* (e.g. `<br/`), this answer only refers to *end tags* (e.g. `<br></br>`).

Comment: @FreeRadical is correct. This answer is technically incorrect, because it confuses `an ending slash` with `an end tag`, and thus misunderstands the spec paragraphs that it quotes. This leads to @YannisDran's confusion. @minitech correctly states what is true.

Answer (score 119):

In HTML 5, the closing slash is *optional* on void elements such `img` (I am adding this because the currently accepted answer only says: "end tags must not be specified for void elements", and does not address closing slashes in void elements).

Citing from http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags (number 6):

> Then, if the element is one of the void elements, or if the element is a foreign element, then there may be a single "/" (U+002F) character. This character has no effect on void elements, but on foreign elements it marks the start tag as self-closing.

Comment: This is not an HTML5 thing. Actually, in earlier Versions of HTML `<br/>` or `<img ... />` were errors.

Comment: @j.j. I quote the HTML5 docs, so I don't understand why do not think it is not HTML5. And indeed, in other versions, such slashed were errors.

Comment: Sure, I meant to say "do we *still* need end slashes in HTML5" is the wrong question. May be I write a full answer with some hisorical links some day. IIRC it was a hard decision for Ian Hickson (the HTML editor) to *allow* trailing slashes in HTML5.

Answer (score 14):

The end slash for void elements is optional.

**Both are valid HTML5:**

```
<img src="some_image.png" />
```

and

```
<img src="some_image.png">
```

Void Elements are:

- `area`
- `base`
- `br`
- `col`
- `embed`
- `hr`
- `img`
- `input`
- `link`
- `meta`
- `param`
- `source`
- `track`
- `wbr`

Besides interesting:

> Void elements can't have any contents (since there's no end tag, no content can be put between the start tag and the end tag).

More details at: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#elements-2

See also the SO-question here:

[Self-closing tags (void elements) in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693939/1066234)

Comment: thanks, I made a regex to remove or add end slash;
find: `<(area|base|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)([^>]*?)\s*?/?>` ;
replace: `<$1$2 />` 
if you're a parser, end slash is nicer because you'll know it's a self closing tag, and not an opening tag (you won't be looking: where's the closing tag?)

Comment: Trailing slash on **HTML 4.01 Transitional** is the same as in HTML 5

Answer (score 5):

Nope. HTML has never required it, even before HTML5. If you plan to use XHTML with HTML features, then yes, it is necessary.

Comment: XHTML is not the same as HTML5, correct? If my DOCTYPE is just "html", I don't need the trailing slashes, correct?

Comment: @CaptSaltyJack - HTML5 covers both ordinary HTML and XHTML. XHTML requires all elements to be closed, but for browsers, the doctype has no effect on the situation. For a fuller explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662508/html-4-html-5-xhtml-mime-types-the-definitive-resource/2664082#2664082

Answer (score 2):

According to [Start Tags](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#start-tags) they are optional.