# Can we put two meta tags in HTML?

Tags: html, meta

Can I put two `meta` tags in a web page?

I want to put:

```
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

so that my web page will not be cached

and:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

so that my web page is IE-compatible.

Comment: Of curse you can do it! Be sure the all in the head section.

Comment: ...in the `<head>` section...

Comment: You could even put 20 meta tags if you wanted to.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible and valid (and actually most of the times even necessary). Basically, you can have an arbitrary number of them, as long as you put all of them into the `head` section of your website. Additionally you should watch out not to have multiple `meta` elements for the same concern.

Please note that for full XHTML compliance your second `meta` is missing the closing `/`. It should be:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

So your final code might be:

```
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

Please note as well, that the order of the `meta` elements is not completely arbitrary, or at least there are some elements where you should pay attention to the order.

E.g., the `meta` element that defines the encoding should be as far at the beginning as possible, since the browser will start re-rendering the website as soon as it approaches this element.

Comment: re the ending `/`, it [depends on the doctype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5)

Comment: That's why I added 'for full XHTML compliance' ;-). But as he used it in his initial example, I wanted to point that out.

Comment: So do we need to put ending / or not for my case?

Comment: As said, it depends on the doctype you used. No matter how you do it: You should either do it everywhere or nowhere.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you may include many, and do not try to combine them.