# preg_replace image tag to other format string

Tags: php, preg-replace

i have to change image tags per php ...

here is the source string ...

```
'picture number is <img src=get_blob.php?id=77 border=0> howto use'
```

the result should be like this

```
'picture number is #77# howto use'
```

I have already tested a lot, but I only get the number of the image as a result ...
this is my last test ...

```
$content = 'picture number is <img src=get_blob.php?id=77 border=0> howto use';
$content = preg_replace('|\<img src=get_blob.php\?id=(\d+)+( border\=0\>)|e', '$1', $content);
```

now `$content` is 77

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost correct. Just drop the `e` flag:

```php
$content = 'picture number is <img src=get_blob.php?id=77 border=0> howto use';
$content = preg_replace('/\<img src=get_blob.php\?id=(\d+)+( border\=0\>)/', '#$1#', $content);
echo $content;
```

Outputs:

```
picture number is #77# howto use
```

See [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for more information about regular expression modifiers in PHP.

Comment: @Talki: be weary, though, your regex, as it now stands is _very_ specific. It requires the `img` tag to contain a `border` attribute, no quotes, and a very specific url pattern (`blob.php?id=`). It also requires an _invalid_ `img` tag (`>` instead of `/>`)!.

Comment: `<img>` is perfectly valid in HTML (not to confuse with XML or XHTML). Ending with `/>` became optional from HTML5 on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5

Comment: @rr: HTML5 is still a w.i.p, and its not fully supported (yet), also XHTML isn't quite dead yet. "XHTML5" does exist. Either way, you're right, it turns out it is valid

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `e` flag, it's not necessairy for regex placeholders, just try this:

```
preg_replace('/\<.*\?id\=([0-9]+)[^>]*>/', '#$1#', $string);
```

This regex *does* assume `id` will be the first parameter of the src url, if this isn't always going to be the case, use this:

```
preg_replace('/\<.*[?&]id\=([0-9]+)[^>]*>/', '#$1#', $string);
```