# Image does not appear above heading

Tags: html, image, twitter-bootstrap

```
 <div class="container marketing">

 <!-- Three columns of text below the carousel -->
 <div class="row">
     <div class="span4">
         <img class="img-circle" img 
            src="../assets/img/examples/GPP-final-app-logo.png">
         <h2>Heading</h2>
         <p>Donec sed odio dui. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. 
            Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit. Morbi leo 
            risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo
            cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
         <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
     </div><!-- /.span4 -->
```

everything seems to be correct, but the image ain't showing up... what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra img in your image tag.  Use the following...

```
<img class="img-circle" src="../assets/img/examples/GPP-final-app-logo.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though your image syntax is wrong, try changing it to:

```
<img class="img-circle" src="../assets/img/examples/GPP-final-app-logo.png"/>
```

Comment: see first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5

You don't need to backslash img elements.

Comment: Good point, although the original tag still contained an extra "img" string.