# Best way to center title text in a div but have the rest of the text left aligned?

Tags: css, html, center

I have 6 divs in two rows of 3 and I want to populate each one with a title that's centered, and image centered and then text under the image that's left aligned.

What's the neatest way to achieve this?

Is it possible to do `.block h2 {...}` and center that way?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/)

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div class="products">

<div class="block"><h2>...</h2><img src="..."><p>...</p></div>

<div class="block"><h2>...</h2><img src="..."><p>...</p></div>

<div class="block"><h2>...</h2><img src="..."><p>...</p></div>

<div class="block"><h2>...</h2><img src="..."><p>...</p></div>

<div class="block"><h2>...</h2><img src="..."><p>...</p></div>

<div class="block"><h2>...</h2><img src="..."><p>...</p></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.products {
    display:inline-block;
}

.block {
    position:relative;
    width:213px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    left:-10px;
}
```

Also, in JSFiddle, why are my "block" `</divs>` red at the end? is it not closed properly?

Comment: jsFiddle is expecting you to close the `img` tags (self close).

Comment: Do you need to close `img` tags? I never do.

Comment: Don't need really, but jsFiddle is probably expecting for xHTML. Who knows?

Comment: Regarding the closing tags: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5

Comment: @MelanciaUK Not a compulsion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the below selectors with `text-align` property

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/2/)

```
.block {
    text-align: center; /* Center text in .block */
}

.block p {
    text-align: left; /* Override centering by using left as a value */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.block h2 {
    text-align: center;   
}

.block img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/6/

Comment: I like this approach for centering the image as it doesn't involve extra markup

Comment: That's also the way W3C wants us to center images. http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add `.block h2 {text-align:center;}` to your css

You need to close your image tags with a / to stop the div's being highlighted in red

I updated the fiddle -http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/8/ . This includes an extra div for centering the image. There would be other ways to approach the image centering

Answer (score 0):

```
.products {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center; /*This will center everything inside products div*/
}

.block {
    position:relative;
    width:213px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    left:-10px;
}
.block p{
   text-align:left; /* This will override the align center 
                       and will align-left only the <p> that are inside block */
}
```

Comment: Please add some comments - what is each part for? What differs from what OP has provided and why?

Comment: Sorry, I hope it's better now!

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kGt54/4/)**

**css**

```
.products {
    display:inline-block;
}

.block {
    position:relative;
    width:213px;
    height:250px;
    background-color:#EEE;
    margin:10px;
    float:left;
    left:-10px;
    text-align:center;
}
.block p{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property: text-align

```
.block h2{
    text-align:center;
}

.block p{
    text-align:center;
}
```

To center the images, you can put the pictures inside a paragraph:

Check the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/833Yq/