# Place image in the middle of a td

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a fixed width with a single < **tr** > and 1 < **td** >.
The < **td** > contains an < **img** > but that image changes from time to time as does the width of the image. How can I place the image on the center of the < **td** >?

I tried to align the < **td** >, but that didn't work. I tried to align the < **img** >, but that didn't work either.

I tried to add 2 < **td** >, one on each side of the < **td** >< **img** > and tried to use css to adjust the width of the 2 empty < **td** > to 100% and the < **td** >< **img** > to auto. That didn't work.

I have to say that this it the first time I use CSS.

**HTML**

```
< table id="table_image" >
     < tr >
        < td id="left" >&nbsp;< /td >
        < td id="button" >< img src="image.jpg" >< /td >
        < td id="right" >&nbsp;< /td >
     < /tr >
< /table >
```

**CSS**

```
< style type="text/css" >

    #table_image {
        border:0px;
        width:1034px;
        height:auto;
    }
    #left {
        width:100%;
        float:left;
    }
    #center {
        border:0px;
        alignment-baseline:middle
    }
    #right {
        width:100%;
        float:right;
    }
< /style >
```

Please help!

Comment: jsfiddle, image or anything else would help us more.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast In HTML5 [end slashes are no longer needed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7366344/1256925). His `<img>` tag is correct.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense! Thank you :)

Comment: I'm new to stack overflow, but what happens when the person obviously marks the wrong one as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how to put the image in the middle of the `<td>` : http://jsfiddle.net/zLS8J/6/
I modified the table and css so you could clearly see the borders.  The main part you should be concerned with is the css for `text-align:center;`

Comment: Here is that demo using the excellent "Place Cage": http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/zLS8J/7/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the HTML center tag ?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_center.asp

Comment: Please do not recommend anyone W3Schools.

Comment: Or the `<center>` tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1798817/why-is-the-center-tag-deprecated-in-html

Comment: Don't use <center>, use CSS instead. Its not supported in HTML5 and was deprecated in HTML 4.01.