# Use slash after HTML tag

Tags: html

I use a HTML theme for my website.
In this theme, there are form tags are shown as `<form/>`.
Why does this theme use a slash after first form tag?

```
<div class="widget-body"> 
   <div class="widget-main"> 
      <form class="form-search" />
       <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" /> 
       <button onclick="return false;" class="btn btn-purple btn-small"> 
          Search <i class="icon-search icon-on-right bigger-110"></i> 
       </button> 
      </form>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: that should end the 'form' element

Comment: Chang  `<form class="form-search" />` to `<form class="form-search">`, otherwise you're closing the form tag prematurely.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after search i found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5?rq=1) that

> in HTML 5, `<foo />` means `<foo>`, the start tag. It is not a
>   "self-closing tag". Instead, certain elements are designated as having
>   no end tag, for example `<br>`. These are collectively called void
>   elements. The slash is just syntactic sugar for people who are
>   addicted to XML. Using the slash in a non-void element tag is invalid,
>   but browsers parse it as the start tag anyway, leading to a mismatch
>   in end tags.

Comment: ... except that in your example, there is a `</form>` tag further down, so there is no mismatch in end tags, It's just a parse error, and the browser  ignores the `/`, which just needs removing.

Comment: @Alohci tnx but please see link

Comment: Of all the things to revert on, uppercase tags and missing slashes were not something anyone should have an issue with. xhml 1.1 was very solid, but 5 should have at least been syntactically readable.

Answer (score 9):

In XHTML syntax, an `<example />` tag is equivalent to `<example></example>` tags.

So, your line of code `<input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" />`, is equivalent to `<input type="text" class="input-medium search-query"></input>`.

Comment: tanx, do you mean input tag is outside form tag?

Comment: No. Your `<input>` tag is still within your `<form>` tag. It's just started and ended within one tag. Does that make sense? Instead of having a closing tag, you already closed it by using a forward slash.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `/` after your form tag, remove it or it won't work ;)