# Is there a difference between <img src = ""> and <img src = ""/>

Tags: html, image, tags

Apologies if this has already been answered, I can't seem to find an answer on here.
My question is, is there a difference between `<img src = "">` and `<img src = ""/>`. 
I have seen both used before, however I normally use `<img src = "">`. If there is a difference what is it, as it does not seem to affect the output. Likewise with `<br>` and `<br/>`. 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/964dokhb/)

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5

Comment: Toby, you didn't do any research..it's a [void element](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements).