# Can I safely omit the closing slash on use and path elements?

Tags: html, svg

Having tested, everything works fine when I remove the closing slashes, however I'm wondering if this will cause a problem on other devices and browsers?

Are the closing slashes necessary on these elements?

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#exercise" /></svg>
<path d="..." />
```

Into

```
<svg><use xlink:href="#exercise"></svg>
<path d="...">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do we still need end slashes in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5)

Comment: It would be useful to cut the answer out your question, and instead post it as its own genuine answer.

Comment: Maybe this question could be answered by another question : why would one want to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing tags on `path` are needed or they will nest. I think it's safe to omit the slash on a `use` element though.

Compare these two:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4557 1024"><path d="M768 1024l-768-768v-256h128l640 640v-640h256v1024h-256z"><path d="M1177.6 1024v-1024h1024v256h-768v128h768v256h-768v128h768v256h-1024z"><path d="M2355.2 1024v-256h768v-128h-768v-640h1024v256h-768v128h768v640h-1024z"><path d="M3532.8 1024v-1024h256v384h512v-384h256v1024h-256v-384h-512v384h-256z"></svg>
    
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4557 1024"><path d="M768 1024l-768-768v-256h128l640 640v-640h256v1024h-256z"/><path d="M1177.6 1024v-1024h1024v256h-768v128h768v256h-768v128h768v256h-1024z"/><path d="M2355.2 1024v-256h768v-128h-768v-640h1024v256h-768v128h768v640h-1024z"/><path d="M3532.8 1024v-1024h256v384h512v-384h256v1024h-256v-384h-512v384h-256z"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closing slashes are still needed. The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/embedded-content-0.html#svg) defines the `svg` element to be embedded content and further states

> The semantics of SVG elements are defined by the SVG specification

As laid out in the [SVG spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/concepts.html#Intro) the svg document is an XML grammar to which the rules for XML apply. Looking at the definitions covering the logical structure of the xml document the [XML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) states, that

> The end of every element that begins with a start-tag must be marked
>   by an end-tag

If the element is empty, an empty-element tag may be used instead. This, however, still requires the closing slash.