# How to remove the end slash from the img tag?

Tags: static, jekyll, slash, kramdown, redcarpet

**Kramdown** is now the default markdown renderer for Jekyll 4.0. I would like to know if there is a way to remove the end slash from the img tag.

For example:

```
![Flowers](flowers.jpg)

<img src="flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" />
```

One way until a few months ago was to using **Redcarpet**, but now is dropped.

How can I do?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: It seems that it's hard coded and non configurable (see [kramdown code](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb#L272)). The only way is to override this method.

Comment: Hi David, thank you. I can override **Kramdown** with a filter or a plugin?

Comment: I've made an answer about that.

Answer (score 4):

As said in my comment, this trailing slash is hard coded in [Kramdown Html converter](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb#L272).

You can override this methods by creating a _plugins/my_img_tag.rb file :

```
module Kramdown

  module Converter

    class Html < Base

      # Overriding method
      def convert_img(el, _indent)
        "<img#{html_attributes(el.attr)}>"
      end

    end

  end

end
```

Note : this plugin will not work on Github pages.

Comment: So, maybe you can approve this answer ;-)

Comment: Yes David :) - I don't understand why *Kramdown* inserts the end slash. In 2020 we still need the /> on tags?

Comment: It's optionnal. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5

Comment: Ok, but I expect from Kramdown/Jekyll a way to disable XHTML. I want 100% control in final output. For example, Hugo provide this functionality.

Comment: kramdown line in question is now https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/blob/master/lib/kramdown/converter/html.rb#L277

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions for this:

The regex below catches what we want:

```
(<img)(.*\n*\t*\s*)(\/>)
```

Then, you can do a replace of the 3rd group:

```
$1$2>
```

---

I've tested with a few variations of the tag img:

[Test using Sublime Text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX6fi.png)

Comment: Oi Alexandre, obrigado. Mas eu utilizo markdown com **Jekyll**, portanto a sua sugestão não me ajuda. Como respondeu o David acima, preciso sovrescrever o Kramdown. O problema é como faze-lo.