# Material-ui 4: how to fix "overly responsive" font sizes when loading app in landscape mode?

Tags: responsive-design, material-ui, font-size

My understanding of Material-UI 4's responsive font scaling is that it takes the "screen" width and scales font sizes based on certain breakpoints. However, I don't explicitly call `responsiveFontSizes()` for my theme, so maybe I'm wrongly assuming that responsive font scaling is involved then this is rather viewport initial scaling? At the moment, I'm using the usual `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />`.

The unfortunate outcome is that the same app when viewed on a tablet in landscape mode has significantly larger fonts compared to when viewing the app in portrait mode. This is especially prominent on common 19:10 screens (10:19 in portrait).

How can I set Material-UI's responsive font scaling based on the shorter dimension of the viewport, so that rotating the viewport doesn't result in ugly font size upscaling?

Comment: Note: HTML does not use and does not need or require a closing slash on any tag and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: can you then please open a bug report on the CRA template: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/cra-template-typescript/template/public/index.html#L6

Comment: btw, https://stackoverflow.com/a/21898502

Comment: Yes, it is allowed, but that doesn't change anything I said. It has no meaning, does nothing, and browsers are instructed to  ignore it.

Comment: Allowing self-terminating elements often make markup generators and generation much simpler and uniform, so what's your problem with self-closing that you need to even to mention it with such verve?

Comment: I don't know how it would make it easier? It's a XML thing and people have complained about having to keep track of closing slashes for years. My point, however, is that putting irrelevant, unnecessary, ignored, do-nothing characters into your HTML makes no sense. It's like putting two periods at the end of a sentence. Why would you do that. Just because you can?