# innerHTML removes closing slash for an image tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I created an example where you can see the issue.

```js
window.onload = function () { 
        console.log(document.getElementById("container").innerHTML)
};
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png" />
</div>

<div id="tree"></div>
```

The result you can see in alert.
When I use innerHTML the closing slash of *img* tag dissapeares for some reason.
How can I get a valid result with the slash in the end?

Comment: You don't need the closing slash unless your doctype is XHTML, which it's not.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question is how can I get the result I expect?

Comment: You don't need to close the tag for void elements (like input or img) , as already said by this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-end-slashes-in-html5). Non void elements (like div or button) must be closed

Comment: You can't. `innerHTML` adds the HTML to the DOM, where the browser takes over. The browser decides it doesn't need the closing slash. You can't convince it otherwise.

Comment: @DDomen thanks for your answer. But read the ending of the question again please.
I need to get  this slash for further converting an svg containing this img into a file.

Comment: They have closed your question, I don't know if it is duplicated. Anyway you can use
`new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(yourElement)` in order to obtain a closing slash, better way then appending it by yourself. Drawback: you will have some more attributes due to xml.