# Why is the last slash of a node missing in xidel output?

Tags: xidel

```
$ xidel --output-format html -s -e 'x:replace-nodes(//script,())' - <<< '<html><head><script>x=1</script><link href="http://example.com" type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' /></head><body>abc</body></html>'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><link href="http://example.com" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"></head><body>abc
</body></html>
```

In the above example, `<link href="http://example.com" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />` is contracted to `<link href="http://example.com" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">`.

Shouldn't the last slash be maintained in the output?

Comment: Do the answers of [7366344](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7366344) and/or [3558119](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3558119) answer your question?

Comment: But my input ends with `/>`, which obviously does not follow the HTML5 convention of just using '>'. I want the output follows the same convention as the input. How to do it?

Comment: Xidel's input is always parsed **and** altered/fixed by its HTML-parser, so I'm not sure you can. If you disagree, you can [file a report](https://github.com/benibela/xidel/issues).

Comment: You could use `--printed-node-format xml`.