Is it possible restrict browser autocomplete to a domain?
My application has a search textfield, and I'd like to offer a autocomplete/autosuggest functionality, preferably without rolling my own.
The input type="search" element appears to suit my purposes.


<input type="search" placeholder="search" name="q"/>



For me, the above input will provide auto complete suggests that appear to come from GitHub.

Though I believe that's because it share the name property with GitHub's issue search, GitHub's issue search element is:
<input 
   type="text" 
   name="q" 
   id="js-issues-search" 
   value="is:issue is:open " 
   class="form-control form-control subnav-search-input input-contrast width-full" 
   placeholder="Search all issues" 
   aria-label="Search all issues" 
   data-hotkey="Control+/,Meta+/">

The concern is - I don't want searches from other websites polluting mine, nor do I want searches from my website polluting others.
How can instruct the browser to constrain the autocomplete to this website only?
I suppose I could put a unique looking name attribute in, but is there a better way?

What you show has inconsistent usage of a closing slash on <input> but no HTML tag needs or uses a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification so you should remove it.

@Rob https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366344/do-we-still-need-forward-slashes-when-closing-void-elements-in-html5
It's allowed, apparently.

Yes, it's allowed for backwards compatibility to XML when we thought we'd all switch over to XHTML years ago, but it does nothing, has no meaning, and browsers ignore it. So it has no value and you gain nothing by putting it there. Instead, follow the web standard written by the browser vendors themselves (Google, Microsoft, Apple, Mozilla, etc.)

can you clarify what exactly you want to show in the autocomplete in order to modify my answer to your needs?
you want user to be provided with a list of preselected values, a list of their previous searches or something else?

Why isn't a unique looking name not an option?

@SalmanArshad For example, let's say API you are submitting the form to expects the field 'search'. Then we'd have to write some custom logic on everyone of our forms to then strip off the unique name.

@dwjohnston Can the submit-handling function not fix the unique name (re-write it into the API's expected name)?

@VC.One yes, you could, but that would be extra work. It would be nice if there was an attribute designed for this use case.

according to the official HTML Standard, autocomplete values are on,off or a <token-list>. I guess that according to what info you want to be auto-completed, you have to provide a list of tokens.
for concrete, examples check the standard

I'm putting an upvote on this answer, as I think it's the closest to being useful. It's possible that the section- tokens might do what we need.

Suggestions are generated based on the field's name attribute. For example, if you set the name as 'username' commonly used usernames will be displayed. The same seems to happen with 'q' that is certainly a commonly used name for question inputs.
To avoid conflicts with other websites, consider using a unique name attribute, such as 'q-my-website' or similar.
An example:
<input 
     type="text" 
     name="q-my-site" 
     id="js-issues-search" 
     value="is:issue is:open " 
     class="form-control form-control subnav-search-input input-contrast width-full" 
     placeholder="Search all issues" 
     aria-label="Search all issues" 
     data-hotkey="Control+/,Meta+/"
>



"For me, the above input will provide auto complete suggests that appear to come from Github".  "I believe that's because it share the name property with Github's issue search"  "The concern is - I don't want searches from other websites polluting mine, nor do I want searches from my website polluting others".

When I test your code (within StackOverflow), I don't get any Github related suggestions. I understand what you mean though. My auto-complete suggestions are as shown below:

Possible Solution:
I appreciate that you don't want the hassle of rolling out your customised search code. Unfortunately for what you want, it will have to be custom-made. The process of having a custom search results can be made easier in some ways...

Use a <datalist> to pre-populate the search bar with some "popular search terms".
Use Cookies to store any future search terms made by the user/IP.
Use Cookies to load any previously searched terms by that same specific user/IP.

How It Works:
You will add a page Cookie on the HTML of the page containing the Search bar. On first load (per user) it can only show your customised suggestions.
As the user searches in the box, what they put (after pressing ENTER) can be stored in a Cookie, so that in future page visits, it appears as though the site is re-calling their last 5 or so previous search terms.
These user strings inside the Cookie can be later used to populate a custom search suggestions on future visits or page reloads (ie: it definitely won't be recalling items from sites like Github or Youtube).
Code Example: (customized listing, no cookies are involved yet)...
Try this setup...
<input type="search" list="search_suggestions" placeholder="search" name="q" />

Versus this below setup (where autocomplete="off" stops other sites polluting your suggestions results)...
<input type="search" list="search_suggestions" placeholder="search" name="q" autocomplete="off" />

When you test this code:


<input type="search" list="search_suggestions" placeholder="search" name="q" autocomplete="off" />

<datalist id="search_suggestions">
  <option value="latest DWJ courses"></option>
  <option value="free courses on DWJ"></option>
  <option value="classes with DW Johnston"></option>
  <option value="physics new 2024"></option>
  <option value="best maths 2024"></option>
  <option value="how to submit essay?"></option>
</datalist>




Put autocomplete="off" in your input. 
This property should turn off the auto complete feature for users.

Use a custom unique name for the input and here the autocomplete's list will not be modified.

If we want to show only our website content as a suggestion to users, we should handle it with JS code, not HTML. In any case you should turn off the auto-complete.



(1) The auto-complete is needed. How to restrict the auto-suggestions to not include outside domains? (2) Run the code snippet and then click the search box to see the suggestions. How can it show the suggestions from only one specific website? (3) AI generated solutions are not useful... in case you tried using it (AI).

(1) if autocomplete NEEDED, we can use a special custom name for our input and here the autocomplete's tokens list is not helping us. But if we want to show "just" our website content as a suggestion to users, we should handle it with js not html. in that case we should TURN OFF the auto-complete
(2) Just use a unique name for input. another useful data is in number (1)
(3) How you find that I used AI for answer the question?
(4) Speaking in a rude tone will not make you generous or a better developer

I'm not sure how you find a rude tone. I'm telling you facts to improve your Answer.  Your first sentence doesn't explain why it works, the second line is not even needed by a programmer at this level. The question is not about how to "turn off the auto complete feature for users" more like how to customize it (eg: show results from required domain only, etc). I will edit to add your comments into your Answer. With real details that speak to another person, it stops looking like a machine generated solution.
