# Why does DOM children property behave differently for empty and non-empty HTML elements?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Say I have an HTML file with the following code:

```
<foo>
    <bar id="bar1"></bar>
    <bar id="bar2"></bar>
    <bar id="bar3"></bar>
</foo>

<script>
    const foo = document.getElementsByTagName("foo")[0];
    const bars = foo.children;
    for (i = 0; i < bars.length; i++) {
        console.log(bars[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Running it in a browser (in my case, Chrome) results in the three `bar` nodes being printed on the console, which is the expected behavior.

However, when I shorten the notation for `bar` nodes as follows

```
<foo>
    <bar id="bar1" />
    <bar id="bar2" />
    <bar id="bar3" />
</foo>
```

the number nodes printed becomes only one. And it seems that, `bar2` is the child of `bar1`, and `bar3` is the child of `bar2`.

Does HTML DOM handle empty elements differently?

Comment: Please use valid HTML, there's no guarantee of how a browser will behave when you give it garbage.

Answer (score 0):

The `/>` notation has no meaning in HTML. It only has meaning in XML.

As far as the HTML DOM is concerned, in your second example you have three `bar` elements (which are unrecognized, might I add) that are nested within one another, with missing end tags, making it equivalent to the following:

```
<foo>
    <bar id="bar1">
        <bar id="bar2">
            <bar id="bar3"></bar>
        </bar>
    </bar>
</foo>
```

In other words, you don't actually have empty elements in your second example (with the exception of `#bar3`) — because `/>` is meaningless in HTML, it doesn't represent an end tag like it does in XML.

Comment: However, I find that W3Schools is saying otherwise http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_elements.asp. You can search for "Empty HTML Elements" in the page.

Comment: @Yuhuan Jiang: W3Schools grossly oversimplifies things. It assumes you're using standard elements that *are* recognized as void elements. But the /> notation itself doesn't actually have any meaning; it's only allowed in HTML5 as a convenience to authors migrating from XHTML. Since "bar" isn't an actual HTML element, all the HTML processor sees is a <bar> start tag that's missing an end tag.

Comment: Do you mean `\>` is not a general notation, and there is a fixed set of elements like `<br />`?

Comment: @Yuhuan Jiang: Yes, in HTML; see also [Are void elements and empty elements the same?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313426/are-void-elements-and-empty-elements-the-same)