# Terminology - The types of elements in HTML

Tags: html

A while ago there was a term that I remembered that described two categories of elements. I forgot the term and I want to know what that term was. The information I can remember is that the first category of elements get their values from within HTML like `<p>` or `<a>` or `<ul>` but there is another category of elements which get their values from "outside" of HTML like `<img>` or `<input type="textbox">`. I want to know the terminology for these types.

Edit - I've went through **Zomry**, **Difster** and **BoltClock**'s answers and didn't get anything. So I remembered some extra piece of information and decided to add it. The two categories are Lazy Opposites of each other. For example if one is called *xyz*, then the other is called *non-xyz*.

Comment: I’m not sure but I think you’re referring to containers versus standalone elements, also named self-closing tags. You get a general “logic” about whether an element belongs to one category or the other, but few exceptions go againts intuition, such as `<button>` and `<canvas>`. Better have a cheatsheet within reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you mean [replaced elements](https://drafts.csswg.org/css22/conform.html#replaced-element) (and non-replaced, respectively)?

However, the distinction between them is not so unambigous. For example, form controls were traditionally considered replaced elements, but the HTML spec currently [explicitly lists them](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/index.html#toc-rendering) as non-replaced (introducing the "widget" term instead).

Comment: @Arno Lorentz: Just to clarify though, replaced and non-replaced are CSS terms, not HTML terms. The concept of a "value" as described in your question doesn't exist in CSS.

Comment: Oh. Learned something new. Thanks @BoltClock.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML specification mentions for tags like `<img>` and `<input>` the following: *Tag omission in text/html: No end tag*.

Tags with an end tag are defined as: *Tag omission in text/html: Neither tag is omissible*.

So as far as I can find, the HTML spec does define a technical name for this, apart from void versus normal elements, so what Watilin pointed out in the comments should be fine: standalone vs containers.

As an added side-note: HTML has a lot more HTML content categories. You can find a complete overview at the HTML spec here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/indices.html#element-content-categories

Also interesting to read to visualize that a bit better: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories

Answer (score 1):

Elements whose contents are defined by text and/or other elements between their start and end tags don't have a special category. Even the HTML spec just calls them normal elements for the most part in [section 8.1.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements).

Elements whose primary values are defined by attributes and that *cannot* have content between their tags are called [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#void-elements). `img` and `input` are indeed two examples of void elements. Note that void elements are not to be confused with empty elements; see the following questions for more details on that:

- [Are void elements and empty elements the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313426/are-void-elements-and-empty-elements-the-same/25314415#25314415)
- [HTML "void elements" so called because without content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447221/html-void-elements-so-called-because-without-content/41447330#41447330)

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="text" id="someField" name="someField">`
With an input selector, you can get a value from it like so (with jQuery):
`$("#someField).val();`

Where as with a paragraph or a div, you don't get a value, you get the text or html.
`<div id="someDiv">Blah, blah, blah</div>` You can get that with jQuery as follows:
`$("#someDiv").html();`

Do you see the difference?