# What is another term for self-closing elements (2 words) (first letter starts with e)

Tags: html, terminology

This is related to the code language: HTML, I have tried words regarding element, but no luck yet.

Comment: In case this is from a crosswords or something, knowing the total length may be useful, as well :)

Answer (score 0):

"Void elements" is another term for self-closing elements according to the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) www.w3.org

Here is a thorough breakdown:
There are six different kinds of elements:

1. void elements
2. template elements
3. raw text elements
4. escapable raw text elements
5. foreign elements and
6. normal elements.

Brief summary:

**Raw text, escapable raw text, and normal elements** have a start tag to indicate where they begin, and an end tag to indicate where they end.

The start and end tags of certain normal elements can be omitted, instances where 
the `<HTML>` element’s start tag may be omitted if the first thing inside the html element is not a comment.

Void elements only have a start tag; end tags must not be specified for void elements.

Foreign elements must either have a start tag and an end tag, or a start tag that is marked as self-closing, in which case they must not have an end tag.

Reference:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/syntax.html#writing-html-documents-elements

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you're looking for "empty elements". That term only has unambiguous meaning in XML. Don't use it when talking about HTML; use "void elements" instead, which is HTML5's new name for the old HTML definition of "empty elements".

See [Are void elements and empty elements the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313426/are-void-elements-and-empty-elements-the-same)