# Rendering <input> into a page from angular factory string variable

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular factory in which there is an object which contents are

```
{
  id:1,
  str:'<h4>Click Here</h4><br><input type="button" value="OK">'
}
```

I want to render this input button at my page but it renders h4 tag successfully but not the input button. What can I do?

Comment: can it be that you are missing the closing tag for input? `/>`

Comment: @eesdil In HTML5, input tags do [not require a closing void tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693939/self-closing-tags-void-elements-in-html5)

Comment: No it is not. @eesdil

Comment: Good to know... :) As the object looks ok otherwise, it would be great to see what is rendering this object... maybe you can make a plunkr?

Comment: I just tested it using `ng-bind-html` and it worked fine. We're going to need to see some more code or an example of the behavior you're seeing. [Working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dj4xkamg/)