# Best practice. <br> or <br />, <img ...> or <img />, etc

Tags: html

I haven't done serious web dev since 2013. I was usually pretty conscious of best practice. Lately as I'm using templates I'm seeing alot of `<img src=""...>` instead of `<img />` such as I had learned. Did something change? Is best practice changed?

Comment: Is the spec you're following HTML or XHTML?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14860492/how-to-close-img-tag-properly/14860541

Comment: I believe this question may be a duplicate of the two questions I just cited.  Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23890716/why-is-the-img-tag-not-closed-in-html  Many answers are quite old, but still valid; there are also many newer answers.

Comment: There's no absolute answer to this question. `<img src="...">` is acceptable according to specs. `<img src="..." />` is more readable and conveys intention more clearly for somebody who's not proficient in HTML.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693939/self-closing-tags-void-elements-in-html5

Answer (score 2):

In HTML (up to HTML 4): use `<br>`

In HTML 5: `<br>` is preferred, but `<br/>` and `<br />` is also acceptable

In XHTML: `<br />` is preferred. Can also use `<br/>` or `<br></br>`

Notes:

- `<br></br>` is not valid in HTML 5, it will be thought of as two line
  breaks.
- XHTML is case sensitive, HTML is not case sensitive.
- For backward compatibility, some old browsers would parse XHTML as
  HTML and fail on 
   but not

Reference:

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML

Comment: Looks like I have some catching up to do.

Comment: In XHTML `<br />` is mandatory. `<br/>` and `<br></br>` are just alternative ways of writing the same thing.